# Alien invasion movie, giant robot aliens with long legs capturing people

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, alien-invasion

So I saw this movie about 10 years ago, when I was about 5 years old. Since I was really young, my memory of it isn't really that great.

I think it may have been an alien invasion movie, but the only scene I remember is that there were these giant robot-alien things:

- I think they had several long legs.
- They had a big glass dome on top of them
- They would grab civilians and drop them in their glass dome.

That's all I remember. If you could please help me out, that would be great.

Again, I was about 5 years old when I watched it, so my memory of it isn't that great, but I hope you know what I'm talking about. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Doesn't sound like a movie a 5 year old should watch, and if the answerer is right definitely is not. How comes it you was able to watch it when you where 5 years old? Just wan't to know to prevent it from happening to my son. :-)

Comment: Seems like a perfect movie for a five-year old, but I remember seeing The Terminator for the first time at that age, so maybe I'm not the best judge.

Comment: I’m 27, but now feel old that the OP was just five when _War of the Worlds_ was released.

Comment: I remember watching a movie with big robot spiders that attacked some cowboys, and they had a big-ass ship dropping them on the ground. Anyone know the movie's name? I'm not talking about War of the Worlds.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86937)

Comment: @user69728 That's Cowboys vs Aliens, I believe

Comment: @Kat Have you found the answer to your question?

Answer (score 55):

By your brief description, I believe the movie you're thinking about is **[*War of the Worlds* (2005)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Worlds_(2005_film))** since:

- It is an alien invasion movie
- It was released in 2005 - just over 10 years ago (at time of writing)
- The aliens capture humans using their distinctive "[Tripod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighting_machine_(The_War_of_the_Worlds))" robots
- The tripod robots capture humans and place them in their "cages" for *further processing*
  [image: Tripod robot from War of the Worlds (2005 movie)]

<sup>[src: http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/f/fb/War_worlds_spielberg_43_x.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120126200527]</sup>

Here's the movie's trailer on YouTube:

And on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407304/?ref_=ext_shr_eml_vi_tt_ov_vi#lb-vi3487629593).

---

You may also be interested to know that the movie was "loosely" based on the novel titled *[War of The Worlds][5]* by [H.G. Wells][6]. The story also has had [several other incarnations][7] including:

- *[The War of the Worlds (1953)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds_(1953_film))* movie
- *[H. G. Wells' War of the Worlds (2005)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._G._Wells%27_War_of_the_Worlds_(2005_film))* direct to DVD movie
- Which inherently could also be the movie you're thinking about
- And several other tv or radio adaptations
- Including that famous radio adaptation, [The War of the Worlds (radio drama)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds_(radio_drama)) which was broadcast over the [Columbia Broadcasting System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBS_Radio_News) radio network. The broadcast was voiced by [Orson Welles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orson_Welles) and appeared to be a news bulletin - apparently causing mass outrage as many listeners believed that it was a real event<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds_(radio_drama)#Public_reaction)</sup>.

Comment: Apparently no less than three separate film adaptations of The War of the Worlds were all released the same year. And until I started reading your answer, I thought there was only one. By the way there is a minor mistake in your answer: You say 2005 was nearly 10 years ago, in fact it was over 10 years ago.

Comment: @kasperd I knew that there was the 1953 adaptation as well as the Tom Cruise one, but I didn't know there were others until I started to *write* this answer :)

Comment: @kasperd Also, the mistake is merely me not conveying what I meant, I meant that it's close to the 10 years specified by the OP.

Comment: The comment thread was straying off-topic, so I [moved it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38553/discussion-on-answer-by-mooz-alien-invasion-movie-giant-robot-aliens-with-long). Please feel free to continue the discussion about War of the Worlds films there, and let me know if I deleted any comments I shouldn't have.

Comment: There's also the Prog Rock iteration of War of the Worlds which turns the original book into a radio play/musical sort of. It's hard to explain until you hear it, but if you like Prog Rock, it's awesome.

Comment: The war of the worlds movie with Tom Cruise pulled heavily from a book set by John Christopher called the Tripods, including the scene of Tom throwing a grenade up inside the machine.

Answer (score 12):

War of The Worlds is a likely candidate, but The '**glass** dome' part makes me think you may be talking about **'Mars Attacks!'** ([IMDB Entry](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116996/)), a Tim Burton film.

The Martian's vehicles, saucers and robots (and, indeed, even their environment suits) all had distinctive glass domes, and I think I remember people being detained in them.

For an example picture, here's [a model of a 'Mars Attacks!' robot](https://manticblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/mars-attacks-robot-450x450.jpg)

There's also an outside chance you're talking about an old BBC Serial, '**Tripods**', but that seems less likely, as I don't think it's aired widely, if at all, anymore.

Comment: omg, i was hoping someone would mention Tripods because I just couldn't recall the title for that series!

Comment: Of course you couldn't recall the title. None of the capped can.

Comment: The Tripods was a series based off the Tripod books by John Christopher. The war of the worlds movie with Tom Cruise pulled heavily from this book set including the scene of Tom throwing a grenade up inside the machine.

Answer (score 4):

You might also be thinking about [Skyline](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1564585/), although in that one the civilians were tractor-beamed up to the alien ship.

There were long-legged robots. There was a glass dome into which civilians were dumped. Where it differs is that there was one big glass dome in the main ship, to which the civilians were tractor-beamed. So might not be it, but it's an outside shot, same as the BBC adaptation of "The Tripods".

Comment: While you and I know that the movie is about an alien invasion, you may want to include some description of it to indicate that it matches the question. Were there ong-legged robots with glass domes?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots If you like, although a link to the IMDB entry is rather better than a description.  There were long-legged robots.  There was a glass dome into which civilians were dumped.  Where it differs is that there was one big glass dome in the main ship, to which the civilians were tractor-beamed.  So might not be it, but it's an outside shot, same as the BBC adaptation of "The Tripods".