# Movie with giant spider-like alien robots kidnapping people

Tags: story-identification, movie

- Giant robots with an oval-looking head with a few of long legs (like spider) but bigger
- Lighting strikes down into the middle of the road and that’s how they came
- They climbed out and starting shooting lasers that would desintegrate the humans they kill but their clothes are not gone
- A family (the main characters) go and try to run and they live but they go to a big ferry or ship. They make it on but those alien robots come and flip the ship, taking all passengers into the water, taking them with their long arms inside of them. The alien robots are either killing them or storing them but they throw out their clothes.
- The family finds a little underground house or something, but the son or boy goes to help someone else up the hill. So he goes and leaves the family but I think he dies.
- the father and daughter hide in the underground bunk house, but the alien robots have moving arm eyes or something, looking for people to capture and kill or take.

I don’t think this is from *War of the Worlds*.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Alien invasion movie, giant robot aliens with long legs capturing people](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125368/alien-invasion-movie-giant-robot-aliens-with-long-legs-capturing-people)

Comment: @Clockwork likely, but we only vote to close story IDs as duplicates if we have confirmation by the OP that it's correct (either through acceptance of the answer or informally in a comment).

Answer (score 13):

This is definitely, 100% the 2005 film *[War of the Worlds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Worlds_(2005_film))*, despite you insisting otherwise. The film stars Tom Cruise and involves him escaping the invasion with his son and daughter, travelling across the US to return his kids to their mother.

- The aliens ride lightening down to their buried machines
- The machines break out of the ground, with the reveal scene being in the middle of a road in a town
- The machines death ray vaporises humans but heaves their clothes intact
- The family (Cruise, and his son and daughter) escape and as part of their travels get on a ferry, which is flipped over by an alien war machine
- The alien machines grab humans and put them in cages carried on the machines sides, and then use the humans as a food source
- The son runs up a hill toward a battle going on between alien war machines and the military
- Cruise and the daughter take refuge in a cellar, and the aliens use a long snake like probe to investigate.

Comment: Are you sure? If so, what is it called? Or at least what episode is it

Comment: @Kev it’s the *film*, War of the Worlds, starring Tom Cruise and released in 2005.  I have linked to it in the answer.

Comment: Oh ok thanks so much

Comment: @Kev there are no episodes, it’s a film, a single thing.  Running time 116 minutes.  It’s got nothing to do with the War of the Worlds series (any of the 1988 series, the new BBC series or the new Fox series), or the 1953 movie, or the 1938 or 1968 radio dramas.  It’s the film linked in the answer.

Comment: It sure sounds like WoW with Tom C. That does not preclude a version someplace, somewhere that copies it -- The Asylum (for example) deliberately makes similar movies to major films, with misleadingly close or even identical titles.

Comment: @releseabe the description is way too on the nose for it to be anything other, and certainly not a B movie made for daytime TV low budget rip off which would have certainly seen everyone involved being sued into oblivion if it were that similar as described...  This isn’t Deep Impact and Armageddon, this would be Deep Impact and Deep Impact The Directors Cut....

Comment: yes but sometimes i just want to open my big yap

Comment: It most certainly _is_ this.

Comment: FWIW, there have been three WotW TV series, so asking about "episodes" is reasonable.

Comment: This movie pulled heavily from the very awesome Tripod book series by John Christopher, even duplicating some of the scenes like Cruise throwing the grenade up inside the Tripod machine.